# Dropwizard metrics how to count for an action without carrying forward the counter value

Tags: counter, reset, dropwizard, metrics, datadog

I have a very simple case where I want to see how many time a user click on the ButtonA in my app. I'm using DropWizard metrics counter to archive this and the coursera reporter to report them to DataDog every 1 minutes.

```
registry.counter("buttonA").inc();
```

But what is happening is that this counter doesn't behave like I thought it would. so for example if the buttonA has been clicked 4 times, the counter will keep the value 4 until the app restart which is not very useful.

Is there an other metrics I'm not aware about that would keep a count and at each reports reset to 0 ? So that on Datadog dashboard I can easily sum all the count and manage to get the exact numbers even if the app is restarted it will not affect the metrics.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is something that does this for you automatically. You have to reset the counter yourself at each reporting interval. Something like this should work:

```
long count = registry.counter("buttonA").getCount();
dataDogReporter.report("buttonA", count);
registry.counter("buttonA").dec(count);
```